# KafkaOffsetMonitor UI css not loading

Tags: css, apache-kafka

I am running a kafka cluster and I want to monitor the various details of kafka. For that, I am using KafkaOffsetMonitor. I have downloaded the already packaged jar and when I am running it, the css for the tool is not loading. Everything is working fine except the css. Can you help me with this? I want to use this tool for a presentation.

https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor/releases/tag/v0.2.1 This is the link from where I downloaded the jar and

```
java -cp KafkaOffsetMonitor-assembly-0.2.1.jar \
     com.quantifind.kafka.offsetapp.OffsetGetterWeb \
     --zk zk-server1,zk-server2 \
     --port 8080 \
     --refresh 10.seconds \
     --retain 2.days
```

this is my run command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall was blocking the content. Turning off the firewall fixed it.